# How to take ownership of T from Arc<Mutex<T>>?

Tags: rust

I want to return a value from a function which is protected by a `Mutex`, but cannot understand how to do it properly. This code does not work:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn func() -> Result<(), String> {
    let result_my = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Ok(())));
    let result_his = result_my.clone();

    let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut result = result_his.lock().unwrap();
        *result = Err("something failed".to_string());
    });

    t.join().expect("Unable to join thread");

    let guard = result_my.lock().unwrap();
    *guard
}

fn main() {
    println!("func() -> {:?}", func());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15a74c1c8b03b65055927d635c5c12b5&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     *guard
   |     ^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Comment: What would you like the behavior of `result_his.lock()` to be after moving the value out of `result_my`?

Comment: Ideally I'd like something accepting `Mutex<T>` by value and yielding `T`, so far I don't need that mutex anymore. But ok, I understand now this could be too complex solution. Should I accept @SBSTP 's answer now or it's better to make my own answer and accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to wrap the result into an `Option` and then take it out:

```
fn func() -> Result<(), String> {
    let result_my = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Ok(()))));
    let result_his = result_my.clone();

    let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut result = result_his.lock().unwrap();
        *result = Some(Err("something failed".to_string()));
    });

    t.join().expect("Unable to join thread");

    let mut guard = result_my.lock().unwrap();
    guard.take().unwrap()
}
```

It seems better than the [`mem::replace` solution proposed by @SBSTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178576/155423) because there is no need to construct an empty `T` for swapping, and it prevents multiple extractions.

Answer (score 33):

In Rust 1.15, you can use [`Arc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap) and [`Mutex::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.into_inner):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn func() -> Result<(), String> {
    let result_my = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Ok(())));
    let result_thread = result_my.clone();

    let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut result = result_thread.lock().unwrap();
        *result = Err("something failed".to_string());
    });

    t.join().expect("Unable to join threads");

    let lock = Arc::try_unwrap(result_my).expect("Lock still has multiple owners");
    lock.into_inner().expect("Mutex cannot be locked")
}

fn main() {
    println!("func() -> {:?}", func());
}
```

[`RwLock::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#method.into_inner) also exists since Rust 1.6.

Comment: Rust 1.70 adds `Arc::into_inner` which guarantees that you can extract the value when you call it on every clone of the `Arc`. Not needed for the OP's usecase, but could be useful for somebody else landing on this question.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Could be useful, but doesn't guarantee that. "Returns the inner value, if the Arc has exactly one strong reference. Otherwise, None is returned and the Arc is dropped".

Comment: @mikerodent That's why I said "when you call it on every clone of the Arc". Exactly one (the final one) of the `Arc` instances will return the data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to transfer ownership of a mutable reference by replacing it with a new value. (the old value is returned and moved)

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::mem;

fn func() -> Result<(), String> {
    let result_my = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Ok(())));
    let result_his = result_my.clone();

    let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut result = result_his.lock().unwrap();
        *result = Err("something failed".to_string());
    });

    t.join();

    let mut guard = result_my.lock().unwrap();
    mem::replace(&mut guard, Ok(()))
}

fn main() {
    println!("func() -> {:?}", func());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea! But in this case it seems that my `Option` solution is even better, because I don't have to construct useless empty `T` second time for `mem::replace` arg (it could be significant when construction is not cheap).

Comment: Well I don't know if you consider `None` to be construction, but `take` uses `mem::replace` and replaces the value by `None`. http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#702

Comment: I mean that for my example `T` is of type `Result<(), String>`, so it's no problem to provide `Ok(())` as `mem::replace` parameter, but if it was something like `fs::File` it could be nontrivial task.