# How to await `JoinHandle`s and update `JoinHandle`s at the same time?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

Is it possible to both read a stream of `Future`s from a set of `JoinHandle<()>` tasks *and* update that set of tasks with new tasks at the same time?

I currently have a `Service` that runs some long tasks. Only thing is, I would actually like to (if possible) add *new* tasks in at the same time -- via a flag sent by some type of `Receiver` channel (not shown below to keep things simple).

Given that in `Service::run` `handles` becomes owned by that function, I would lean towards "no", this is not possible. Is this true? If this isn't possible given my setup, is there some way I could tweak the code below to make this possible?

I read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30573374/12982315) that wrapping `HashMap` in an `Option` allows me to use `.take()` in `Service::run` since the value needs to be owned in order to call `.into_values()`. However, problem with this is that `.take()` consumes the value in the `Mutex`, leaving `None` in its wake.

Here is my minimal reproducible example (did not compile this, but should give the idea):

```rust
use tokio::{sleep, time::Duration, task::JoinHandle};
use async_std::{Mutex, Arc};
use futures::{
    stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt},
    Future,
};

type Handles = Arc<Mutex<Option<HashMap<String, JoinHandle<()>>>>>;

fn a_task() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
  async move {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(3)).await;
  }
}


fn the_update_task(handles: Handles) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
  async move {
    // would like to update `handles` here as I get new data from a channel
    // calling .take() in Service::run nukes my handles here :(
  }
}

struct Service {
  handles: Handles,
}

impl Service {
  fn new() -> Self {
    let handles = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(HashMap::default())));
    let handle = tokio::spawn(the_update_task(handles.clone());
    Self { handles }
  }

  async fn add_a_task(&mut self, id: String) {
    let handle = tokio::spawn(a_task());
    self.handles.lock().await.as_mut().unwrap().insert(id, handle);
  }

  async fn run(self) {
    let Service { handles, .. } = self;
    let mut futs = FuturesUnordered::from_iter(
       handles.lock().await.take().unwrap().into_values()
    );
    while let Some(fut) = futs.next().await {
      info!("I completed a task! fut:?}");
    }
  }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
   let mut srvc = Service::new();
   srvc.add_task("1".to_string()).await;
   srvc.add_task("2".to_string()).await;

   let handle = tokio::spawn(srv.run());
   handle.await;
}
```

I have tried

- Using `Arc(Mutex(HashMap))`
- Using `Arc(Mutex(Option(HashMap)))`

I seem to arrive always at the same conclusion:

- I cannot both *own* `handles` in `Service::run` *and* update `handles` (even a copy/reference) from other part of the code

Comment: You can push additional futures into a FuturesUnordered, but theres some subtly there in that they won't be polled until a future that was in the collection is woken. Though you could arrange that with some sort of signal.

Comment: Thanks user1937198 I ended up going this route and just pushing the new tasks to the `FuturesUnordered` instead of trying to hack a solution involving `handles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question here with the help of @user1937198's comment.

The solution was to update a reference to the `FuturesUnordered` directly with new tasks, as opposed to being concerned with `handles`. This simplifies things quite a bit.

```rust
use tokio::{sleep, time::Duration, task::JoinHandle};
use async_std::{Mutex, Arc};
use futures::{
    stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt},
    Future,
};

fn a_task() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
  async move {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(3)).await;
  }
}


fn the_update_task(futs: Arc<Mutex<FuturesUnordered>>) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
  async move {
    // Just push another task
    let fut = tokio::spawn(a_task());
    futs.lock().await.push(fut);
  }
}

struct Service {
  handles: HashMap<String, JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Service {
  fn new() -> Self {
    let handles = HashMap::default();
    Self { handles }
  }

  async fn add_a_task(&mut self, id: String) {
    let handle = tokio::spawn(a_task());
    self.handles.insert(id, handle);
  }

  async fn run(self) {
    let Service { handles, .. } = self;
    let futs = Arc::new(Mutex::new(FuturesUnordered::from_iter(handles.into_values())));

    tokio::spawn(the_update_task(futs.clone())).await.unwrap();

    while let Some(fut) = futs.lock().await.next().await {
      info!("I completed a task! fut:?}");
    }
  }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
   let mut srvc = Service::new();
   srvc.add_task("1".to_string()).await;
   srvc.add_task("2".to_string()).await;

   let handle = tokio::spawn(srv.run());
   handle.await;
}
```