# Conditionally move T out from Rc<T> when the count is 1

Tags: rust, reference-counting, ownership-semantics

Is there a way to move an object from an `Rc<T>` when the count is `1`? I am thinking about how one would implement:

```
fn take_ownership<T>(shared: Rc<T>) -> Result<T, Rc<T>> { ... }
```

The semantics would be that you get `T` if the count is `1` and you get back `shared` otherwise so you can try again later.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap

Comment: Thanks! Ok, this is embarrassing. When I initially search the documentation I looked for an Optional<T> return and that is why I missed this function. Then I realized Result would be more useful, but I was already convinced the answer was not in the docs due to the previous search. Logical fail :(

Comment: @red75prime: Might as well post this as an answer so it can be accepted and we can all move on :)

Comment: See also [How to take ownership of T from Arc<Mutex<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29177449/155423).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library provides the [`Rc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap) function:

> ```
> fn try_unwrap(this: Rc<T>) -> Result<T, Rc<T>>
> ```
>
> Returns the contained value, if the `Rc` has exactly one strong
>   reference.
>
> Otherwise, an `Err` is returned with the same `Rc` that was passed in.
>
> This will succeed even if there are outstanding weak references.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> use std::rc::Rc;
>
> let x = Rc::new(3);
> assert_eq!(Rc::try_unwrap(x), Ok(3));
>
> let x = Rc::new(4);
> let _y = Rc::clone(&x);
> assert_eq!(*Rc::try_unwrap(x).unwrap_err(), 4);
> ```