# Is there a shared pointer from which it is possible to steal data?

Tags: rust

I want to share a structure `Foo` between several other structures
with the ability to extract this data. All other holders of this structure will see the value disappear.

Pseudocode:

```
if boo.ref_to_foo.is_valid() {
   let foo: Foo = boo.ref_to_foo.steal(); //1
} else {
   //after executing 1 one time all come here 
}
```

I do not need multithreading.

Is `Rc<RefCell<Foo>>` what I want? `Deref for Rc` + `RefCell::borrow_mut` + `Option::take`, or maybe some simpler way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a shared pointer from which it is possible to steal data?

No, but you have all the building blocks you need to create one. Since you

- want to change the value, you need the *interior mutability* provided by `RefCell`.
- want to share ownership, you need `Rc`.
- want to have the possibility of having a value or not a value, you need `Option`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let foo1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Some(Foo)));
    let foo2 = foo1.clone();

    if foo1.borrow().is_some() {
        let stolen = foo1.borrow_mut().take();
    } else {
        println!("Already stolen!")
    }

    if foo2.borrow().is_some() {
        let stolen = foo2.borrow_mut().take();
    } else {
        println!("Already stolen!")
    }
}
```

If you felt like it, you could probably wrap all this up into a single type.

See also:

- [How to take ownership of T from Arc<Mutex<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29177449/155423)
- [Conditionally move T out from Rc<T> when the count is 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45530536/155423)