# the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for Type

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, rust-tokio, rust-tonic, prost

I'm trying to move some data around b/w different threads but am getting the ole Copy trait-not-implemented error. Here's some code:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

/// Start external crates mocked here

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct DecodeError {
    inner: Box<Inner>,
}
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Inner {}
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Connection {}

pub trait Message: core::fmt::Debug + Send + Sync {
    fn decode<B>(mut buf: B) -> Result<Self, DecodeError>
    where
        B: bytes::Buf,
        Self: Default,
    {
        // do stuff
        let mut message = Self::default();
        Ok(message)
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct Request {}
impl Message for Request {}
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct Response {}
impl Message for Response {}

pub struct OtherResponse {}
pub enum ReplyError {
    InvalidData,
}
pub struct EventMessage {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

pub struct Subscription {}

impl Subscription {
    pub async fn next(&self) -> Option<EventMessage> {
        Some(EventMessage { data: vec![] })
    }
}
/// End external crates mocked here

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Publisher<T> {
    connection: Connection,
    subject: String,
    resource_type: PhantomData<*const T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum PublishError {
    SerializeError(String),
    PublishError(String),
}

pub type PublishResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, PublishError>;

impl<T: Message> Publisher<T> {
    pub fn new(connection: Connection, subject: String) -> Self {
        let resource_type = PhantomData;

        Publisher {
            connection: connection,
            subject,
            resource_type,
        }
    }
    pub async fn publish(&self, msg: T) -> PublishResult<()>
    where
        T: Message,
    {
        // do stuff to msg
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let node = Node::new("127.0.0.1", "node".into())
        .await
        .expect("connecting to NATS");
    let p: Publisher<Request> = node.get_publisher("TOPIC".into());
    let _submission_replyer: AsynkReplyer<Request, Response> = node
        .get_replyer("request".into(), move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| async {
            let mut req = req.clone().lock().unwrap();
            p.clone().publish(*req);
            Ok(Response {})
        })
        .await;

    Ok(())
}

pub struct Node {
    name: String,
    connection: Connection,
}

pub type ReplyResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, ReplyError>;

impl Node {
    pub async fn new(_nats_url: &str, name: String) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        env_logger::init();

        let connection = Connection {};
        Ok(Node { name, connection })
    }

    pub fn get_publisher<T>(&self, subject: String) -> Publisher<T>
    where
        T: Message + Default,
    {
        Publisher::new(self.connection.clone(), subject)
    }

    pub async fn get_replyer<Req, Resp, Fut>(
        &self,
        subject: String,
        callback: impl Fn(Arc<Mutex<Req>>) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static + Copy,
    ) -> AsynkReplyer<Req, Resp>
    where
        Req: Message + Default + 'static,
        Resp: Message + Default,
        Fut: Future<Output = ReplyResult<Resp>> + Send,
    {
        AsynkReplyer::new(&self.connection, subject, callback).await
    }
}

pub struct AsynkReplyer<Req, Resp> {
    request_type: PhantomData<Req>,
    response_type: PhantomData<Resp>,
}

impl<Req: Message + Default + 'static, Resp: Message + Default> AsynkReplyer<Req, Resp> {
    pub async fn new<Fut>(
        connection: &Connection,
        subject: String,
        callback: impl Fn(Arc<Mutex<Req>>) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static + Copy,
    ) -> AsynkReplyer<Req, Resp>
    where
        Fut: Future<Output = ReplyResult<Resp>> + Send,
    {
        Self::start_subscription_handler(Subscription {}, callback).await;

        AsynkReplyer {
            request_type: PhantomData,
            response_type: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub async fn start_subscription_handler<Fut>(
        subscription: Subscription,
        callback: impl Fn(Arc<Mutex<Req>>) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static + Copy,
    ) where
        Fut: Future<Output = ReplyResult<Resp>> + Send,
    {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                match subscription.next().await {
                    Some(msg) => {
                        Self::handle_request(msg, callback).await;
                    }
                    None => {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /// Decodes + spins up another task to handle the request
    pub async fn handle_request<Fut>(
        msg: EventMessage,
        callback: impl Fn(Arc<Mutex<Req>>) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static + Copy,
    ) -> ReplyResult<()>
    where
        Fut: Future<Output = ReplyResult<Resp>> + Send,
    {
        let decoded = Req::decode(msg.data.as_slice()).map_err(|_| ReplyError::InvalidData)?;

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match callback(Arc::new(Mutex::new(decoded))).await {
                Ok(response) => {
                    // do stuff
                }
                Err(e) => {}
            }
        });
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Publisher<Request>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied in `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`
  --> src/main.rs:93:10
   |
93 |           .get_replyer("request".into(), move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| async {
   |  __________^^^^^^^^^^^___________________-
   | |          |
   | |          within `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`, the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `Publisher<Request>`
94 | |             let mut req = req.clone().lock().unwrap();
95 | |             p.clone().publish(*req);
96 | |             Ok(Response {})
97 | |         })
   | |_________- within this `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`
   |
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`

error[E0277]: `*const Request` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:93:10
   |
93 |           .get_replyer("request".into(), move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| async {
   |  __________^^^^^^^^^^^___________________-
   | |          |
   | |          `*const Request` cannot be sent between threads safely
94 | |             let mut req = req.clone().lock().unwrap();
95 | |             p.clone().publish(*req);
96 | |             Ok(Response {})
97 | |         })
   | |_________- within this `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`
   |
   = help: within `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*const Request`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `PhantomData<*const Request>`
note: required because it appears within the type `Publisher<Request>`
  --> src/main.rs:53:12
   |
53 | pub struct Publisher<T> {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`

error[E0277]: `*const Request` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:93:10
   |
93 |           .get_replyer("request".into(), move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| async {
   |  __________^^^^^^^^^^^___________________-
   | |          |
   | |          `*const Request` cannot be shared between threads safely
94 | |             let mut req = req.clone().lock().unwrap();
95 | |             p.clone().publish(*req);
96 | |             Ok(Response {})
97 | |         })
   | |_________- within this `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`
   |
   = help: within `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `*const Request`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `PhantomData<*const Request>`
note: required because it appears within the type `Publisher<Request>`
  --> src/main.rs:53:12
   |
53 | pub struct Publisher<T> {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:93:40: 97:10]`
```

I can't (or can I) add the `Copy` attribute on the `Publisher` struct but that wont work since not all of its fields implement `Copy`. Despite this I've commented out the fields in `Publisher` that don't impl `Copy` and added the attribute to it just to see, and with that approach I get:

```
the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `Request`
```

Request is a `protobuf` based struct compiled using the prost lib. I'm not able to add the `Copy` attribute to that because of some of its fields not implementing `Copy` such as `String` and `Timestamp`.

I'm wondering if the design here is just inherently bad or if there's a simple fix.

Comment: Please provide a better [mre]. It is not entirely clear what `node` is in that context, and `use` declarations from external crates are missing. Ideally, we should be able to copy your code and reproduce the same error. And speaking of error, please post the full error from the compiler. See also the [Rust tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) for additional guidance.

Comment: appreciate the feedback, updated with more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, you've constrained that the `Fn` is `Copy` because you are passing it to multiple `tokio::spawn` calls. You've found that `Copy` is very restrictive, however `Clone` is not. You should use it instead and simply call `.clone()` when you handle the new request:

```
Self::handle_request(msg, callback.clone()).await;
```

Then the only errors are `'*const Request' cannot be sent between threads safely`. The compiler does not automatically implement `Send` or `Sync` for pointers because it doesn't know if that's safe, but your `Fn` needs to be called from different threads. Fortunately, you don't need to worry about that. Whether your `PhantomData<*const T>` is there simply to satisfy the compiler or to enforce specific variance, you can get the same result like this:

```
resource_type: PhantomData<fn() -> *const T>
```

Then, now that we've fixed the type constraint errors, the compiler now produces errors about lifetimes:

- `req.clone().lock().unwrap()` doesn't work because the result of `.lock()` is tied to the value from `req.clone()`, but that gets dropped immediately. The fix is that the `.clone()` is unnecessary and can be removed.
- `p.clone().publish(*req)` doesn't work since dereferencing a `MutexLockGuard` cannot provide a owned value, only a reference. You can fix this by adding a `.clone()` instead. If instead you think the `Arc` parameter is exclusive, you can get ownership by following the advice here: [How to take ownership of T from Arc<Mutex<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177449/how-to-take-ownership-of-t-from-arcmutext)
- The last lifetime error is a bit fuzzy because it has to do with the lifetime of the returned `Future` being tied to the `req` parameter. This can be fixed by using `async move { }` but then `p` is moved out of the closure into the future, meaning it is no longer `Fn`. What you want is to *move* `req` but move a *clone* of `p`. You can do this like so:

  ```
  move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| {
      let p = p.clone();
      async move {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```
- *"now I'm trying to resolve errs related to `await`-ing `p.publish`"* - the error has to do with the lock now persisting across an `await` point, but since the mutex guard doesn't implement `Send`, the `Future` cannot be `Send`. You can fix this by locking and cloning in one step, so the lock isn't held:

  ```
  let req = req.lock().unwrap().clone();
  p.publish(req);
  Ok(Response {})
  ```

See this compiling on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fdaa61d81c7241ffbdab795ce1a4ecc). There are still a number of warnings that should be addressed (unused `Result`s), but I hope this gets you on the right path.

Comment: thank you for the level of detail! this is great, now I'm trying to resolve errs related to await-ing `p.publish`

Comment: I've updated my answer and playground link to address your comment. If this has helped, consider upvoting or even accepting this answer. It lets others know the answer was beneficial and rewards users for their efforts.

Comment: thx fren, I've accepted but can't upvote due to low reputation

Answer (score 0):

It is really very difficult to help you with this information. The full error code would probably be useful.

Anyway, in "impl Node ... get_replyer()" you see that's callback should return somehink that's implement Copy

```
pub async fn get_replyer<Req, Resp, Fut>(
    &self,
    subject: String,
    callback: impl Fn(Arc<Mutex<Req>>) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static + Copy,
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------^
) -> AsynkReplyer<Req, Resp>
```

In main

```
let _submission_replyer: AsynkReplyer<Resuest, Response> = node
    .get_replyer(
    "request".into(),
        move |req: Arc<Mutex<Request>>| async {
            
            let mut req = req.lock().unwrap();
            p.publish(*req);
            
            Ok(Response {
                header: None,
                response: Some(OtherResponse {
                    request: None,
                    status: 0,
                }),
            })
//-----------^------------------------------- Return a enum std::result::Result
        },
    )
    .await;
```

std::result::Result implement Copy but wath about Response? The error is showed at this point?

Comment: I don't think the issue has to do with the Response type implementing `Copy`, because when I remove the `p.publish(*req)` and just return `Ok(Response{..})` it compiles

Comment: Well a good information :-) and `p.publish(req.clone())` ?